# SSRS 2014 I cannot open http://localhost/Reports due to permissions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I've looked at a number of potential solutions to the but nothing seems to work.
Basically, I have installed SQL Server 2014 on my own PC.
Everything works fine with the exception of SSRS

Initially, inputting the URL `http://localhost/Reports` returned a blank screen.
Then, after a bit of research and playing around, I made a little progress.
Now, despite me been an admin on my own machine!, it's comes back with:

User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows UAC restrictions have been addressed.
As I say, there are a couple of 'potential' solutions but they require access to the URL - which I simply cannot get.

I feel this is a security related problem but have tried all sorts of potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Open the browser with run as Administrator.

If you get any prompt for username and password. Change your intranet browser setting.

Comment: Thanks, this did answer one part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer and it seems to be a combination of things.

Via Reporting Services Configuration Manager Add an additional HTTP identity for both the web Service URL and Report Manager URL.

Set Host Header Name to localhost
Set TCP Port to 8080

Note, I also found that 80 clashed with Skype causing a 'Page cannot be displayed' error
Although I have amended my Skype setting, I also amended the SSRS port
I'm not sure how crucial this is but it worked for me

Through Control Panel
Search for UAC, select Change User Account Control Settings
Amend to Never Notify
I am still uncomfortable with this but have found no other way of getting this to work.